# Find the area of the surface obtained by rotating the curve about x-axis

Tags: calculus

y= $(9-x^2)^.5$ $; 0<=x<=2$

I did the $\int_0^2$ and put that into the $$SA = \int_0^2 2\pi (\sqrt{9-x^2})*\sqrt{1+(-x/\sqrt{9-x^2})^2} $$

My answer came to be $6\pi$

It is supposed to be $12\pi$ however I manged to cancel my remaining $2$
after multiplying $(f'(x))^2$ letting $u= 9-x^2$ and $du = -2x$ making $dx= (1/-2x)$

Comment: You should wind up with $\displaystyle6\pi\int_0^2\,dx$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int_0^2 2\pi (\sqrt{9-x^2})\cdot\sqrt{1+(-x/\sqrt{9-x^2})^2}dx
&=\int_0^2 2\pi (\sqrt{9-x^2})\cdot\sqrt{\dfrac{9-x^2+x^2}{9-x^2}}dx\\
&=\int_0^2 2\pi\sqrt{9}\,dx\\
&=6\pi\int_0^2dx\\
&=6\pi x{\huge\vert}_0^2=12\pi
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

When simplified, the integrand is $6\pi$, so on integration and applying the given limits, you get the required answer $12\pi$